# Friendly ID for duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-url, slug, friendly-id

Let's say we have 2 posts with the same titles: "superheros". The first post should have url superheros-alternative-1 and the second one should have superheros-alternative-2. 
The problem is that when I am updating a title of one of these posts, the url should change for both of them. I mean if I change a title to "marvel", then the urls should become the following 
 marvel-alternative-1 and marvel-alternative-2.
Now I have the next code

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_update :update_slug

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank? || title_changed?
  end

  def update_slug
    title = Post.find(self.id).title
    Post.where(title:title).each do |post|
      post.update_column(:title,self.title)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So, what is your __question__ exactly? You don't have one in a post.

Comment: Oh sorry, the question was - "How to update URL of the main page and its copies when we update their title?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `update_column` for this, [because it will not trigger the callbacks, validations and such](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns), so, friendly_id will not update your slug. Update the model object attribute and call `.save` instead.

Also, you can update other records after you updated your regular one (in `after_save` callback) - there you will have access to original title and new one, without need to do additional `Post.find(self.id)`

Comment: Yes, you are right, that `update_column`doesn't call callbacks. You are probably right that a better solution would be to make this operation in a controller and not in a model. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArtemGalas I meant [`after_save` ActiveRecord callback in the model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), not in the controller. ;)